# slimScroll destroy doesn't unbind the scroll events

Tags: javascript, jquery, slimscroll

I'm using [slimScroll jQuery plugin](//github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll) and it seems that the destroy option doesn't completely destroy the plugin effect on the site.

For example, if you try to destroy the plugin and then scroll over the previously scrollable content, the site scrolling functionality stops working. You will be able to scroll using the scrollbar, not not by using the mouse wheel / trackpad.

[Here's a reproduction of the bug](https://jsfiddle.net/mdp0a9o0/1/)

Notice a couple of things:

- Scrolling with mouse wheel / trackpad over the previously scrollable element blocks the scrolling.
- Scrolling outside the previously scrollable element works as expected.
- If you scroll the slimScroll until its bottom before destroying it, when destroying it, it works properly as it should in any occasion.

I've already [reported it in the repository](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/issues/165), but no answers are given. It seems its kind of abandoned.
I tried [different](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/issues/138) proposed [solutions](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/pull/144), but none of them work properly.

The lack of a proper method to destroy the plugin seems to be the problem...

Used code in jsfiddle:

```
$('.scrollable').slimScroll({
    allowPageScroll: true,
    height: '250px',
    size: '10px',
    alwaysVisible: true
});

$('.destroy').click(function(){
    $('.scrollable').slimScroll({
        destroy:true
    });
});
```

Comment: What I did in a current project, although it's not the most efficient way, is clone the element I wish to make scrollable before I make it scrollable. And when I want to get rid of it, I just replace it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the plugin is not removing the registered events. This should fix the problem:

```
$('.destroy').click(function(){
    $('.scrollable').slimScroll({
        destroy:true
    });

    var $elem = $('.scrollable'),
    events = jQuery._data( $elem[0], "events" );

    if (events) {
        jQuery._removeData( $elem[0], "events" );
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for it, it seems to work, need to test it a bit more but... Why do you use `jQuery._` instead of `$.`?

Comment: Ok, I see " jQuery’s event data can still be accessed via jQuery._data(element, "events") but be aware that this is an internal data structure that is undocumented and should not be modified." Sounds kind of a *hackFix* then, but I guess this is the only way?

Comment: When trying to use `$._removeData( $elem[0], "events" );` inside another plugin to disable slimScroll I'm getting the error  `undefined is not a function`.

Comment: @Alvaro This data structure is used for storing the registered event handlers in jQuery. Although it's not documented is't well known and widely used. Prior to jQuery 1.9 the "events" object was accessed from $('selector').data('events') and in 1.9 and later releases deprecated. After 1.9 we should use $._data(element, key). As for your last comment - Are you sure that inside the other plugin $ is referring to jQuery object? Also what is the jQuery version you are using?

Comment: Does $elem contains any matched elements? You may add a check for that: var $elem = $('.scrollable'); if($elem[0]) {// get and remove events data}

Comment: Can it be because I'm using those lines you recommended inside the same plugin which initializes the slimScroll ?

Comment: You mean you are modifying the slimScroll plugin?

Comment: Nop. I'm using slimScroll inside another plugin, but when destroying my plugin I want to destroy slimScroll as well. 
And yeah, `$elem` and `events` contain data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64642/discussion-between-zhivko-donev-and-alvaro).